# Deciphering an IIS6 Httperr log file

Tags: iis-6, logging

We have a Windows 2003 R2 SP2 server with iis6 that is creating a 1024kb httperr file every minute. I can't figure out what I'm looking at. Here's a snippet:

2010-03-24 13:15:05 10.53.2.35 1667 10.53.2.12 80 HTTP/1.1 PUT /hserver.dll?&V01|&IMAC=0080646077AB|CID=32|CN=LWT0080646077AB|ED=1|IP=10.53.2.35|SM=255.255.255.0|GW=10.53.2.1|SN=10.53.2.255|DM=logs.com|1D=10.53.2.12|2D=10.101.2.12|0D=1|AL=/usr/sbin/netxserv|AV=4.1.0.0|CP=VIAüEstherüprocessorüü800MHz|CPS=800|RM=190512|B1=1.18|PD2=1024x768x16ü@ü60Hz|IM=6.6.2-02|CI=3600|SN#=6KHDG301300|OS=23|VI=1|P1=24|TZO=-301|TZ=CDT|FS=128|MD=2003-04|CO=|LO=|AP0=BaseüSystem|NA|6.6.2-02|AP1=RapportüAgent|NA|4.1.0-3.26|AP2=TrueType|NA|6.8.0-3.4|AP3=WebFonts|NA|2.0.4-3.6|AP4=TrueTypeüFonts|NA|6.8.0-3.5|AP5=Network_login|NA|1.0.0-1.0.3|AP6=ScreenüSaver|NA|3.13|AP7=DMonitor|NA|1.0.0-0.4.0|AP8=MozillaüFirefox_15|NA|1.5.0.8-3.6|AP9=RemoteüShadow|NA|3.17|AP10=RemoteüDesktop|NA|1.6.0-1.0|AP11=SNMP|NA|5.1.3.1-3.13|AP12=LinuxüPrinting|NA|3.8.27-3.33|AP13=SSH|NA|3.8.1-3.25|AP14=ThinPrint|NA|6.2.87-0.2|AP15=XDMCP|NA|6.8.0-3.29|AP16=Ericom|NA|8.2.0-3.29|AP17=Daylightüsavingütimeüupdate|NA|1.1.0-1.0.0| 411 - LengthRequired -

What on earth am I looking at?

Nothing in the system or app logs.

Finally, in iis manager, Default Web Site label has boxes instead of spaces. Very odd.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this looks to me like some application adding some sort of SNMP logging in your HTTPErr using HTTP.sys. What do you have hosted on IIS?

Looks like Ericom.

Comment: Turns out it is related Wyse thin clients.